# Mediawiki API - limit search (srsearch) to particular category

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Is there a way to limit Mediawiki's `srsearch` facility to a particular category? For example is it possible to restrict the below search

```
/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=relativity
```

to the [Category:Alert_Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Albert_Einstein) category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what search engine you are using. CirrusSearch, for example, can do that with the [`incategory:`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch#Filters_.28intitle:.2C_incategory:_and_linksto:.29) keyword.

Comment: I am searching the [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) so if they have CirrusSearch enabled then it could work. I'll try and pass that parameter to see if it works. Or if you happen to know either way whether they have CirrusSearch enabled then feel free to let me know.

Comment: Yes, Wikimedia sites use CirrusSearch.