# Recursive "incategory" CirrusSearch query

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387550/mediawiki-api-limit-search-srsearch-to-particular-category) I'd like to know if there is a way to perform a recursive search within a particular MediaWiki category. Currently that only seems to search within the category given, not sub-categories.

The only alternative I found was to concatenate all the sub-pages into one big query but does not seems to scale for really large categories as MediaWiki (on the Commons) says `Query was not understood. Please make it simpler.`.

What other options are there to recursively search within a particular category?

Comment: No. MediaWiki categories are not hierarchical, so you will encounter loops (Category:A < Category:B < Category:A), category trees branching and re-merging, and all kinds of other weird things. 

In large wikis, such as Wikipedia, it is also not very useful, because there is often no well defined ontology for categorization. If you traverse the category of the nations of the world on enwp, for instance, you will get the article about the pope somewhere in there (because the popes are categorized under the Vatican City State).

Comment: You might want to check out how [Deepcat](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Nova_Resource:Catgraph/Deepcat) does it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @leo - feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @FredClausen done for them now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. MediaWiki categories are not hierarchical, so you will encounter loops (Category:A < Category:B < Category:A), category trees branching and re-merging, and all kinds of other weird things. In large wikis, such as Wikipedia, it is also not very useful, because there is often no well defined ontology for categorization. If you traverse the category of the nations of the world on enwp, for instance, you will get the article about the pope somewhere in there (because the popes are categorized under the Vatican City State).

That's why [Deepcat](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Nova_Resource:Catgraph/Deepcat) had to be developed.